# ios 11 Search Bar doesn't show with navigationItem

Tags: search, navigation, swift4, searchbar, navigationcontroller

I'm having an issue where my search bar (embedded in a table view) doesn't show no matter what I do. It's just not there when I implement the iOS 11 navigationItem code. Search controller code is below. THANK YOU!

```
func configureSearchBar() {            

            resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                resultSearchController.loadViewIfNeeded()
            } else {
                let _ = self.resultSearchController.view
            }

            let searchField = resultSearchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField
            searchField.font = DifferentScreens.searchField()
            resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            resultSearchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Gifts"

            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

                navigationItem.searchController = resultSearchController
                navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
            } else {

                giftTableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar
            }

            resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
            resultSearchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
            resultSearchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 235/255, blue: 235/255, alpha: 1)
            definesPresentationContext = false
        }
```

Comment: So far your search controller code is okay to show in iOS 11, please check the other UI constraint.  paste your full viewcontroller code.

Answer (score 0):

I have resigned to implementing a UISearchBar from interface builder. It seems to be working okay.